# How to change the CSS of the active toggle button using pseudo CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, material-design, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I have multiple toggle buttons on my web page. I am using `checkbox` input control with some CSS to get a material toggle button design. When I change the state of any of the toggle buttons, the CSS effects are reflected on the first toggle. How can i apply the effect on just the active toggle.

```
<div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle" class=""></label>
  </div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle" class=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS I am using.

```
.material-toggle {
  height: 22px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 12px;
}

.material-toggle input:empty {
    margin-left: -9999px;
}

.material-toggle input:empty ~ label {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:before, 
.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:after {
  position: absolute;
    display: block;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:before {
    top: 3px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

input.switch:empty ~ label:after {
    top: -1px;
    left: -9px;
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 8px;
    bottom: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 0.1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.material-toggle input:checked ~ label:before {
    background-color: #1e88e5;
}

.material-toggle input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 15px;
  background-color: #1565c0;
  border-color: #1565c0;
}
```

I am attaching a [codepen](http://codepen.io/maskaravivek/pen/yaOBoX) for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to have multiple toggle buttons, you need to use IDs, but you have the same IDs in both toggles, which can't happen because IDs are unique, so change the ID and the `label for` to target those IDs.

```css
.material-toggle {
  height: 22px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 12px;
}
.material-toggle input:empty {
  margin-left: -9999px;
}
.material-toggle input:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:before,
.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.material-toggle input:empty ~ label:before {
  top: 3px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
input.switch:empty ~ label:after {
  top: -1px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 8px;
  bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}
.material-toggle input:checked ~ label:before {
  background-color: #1e88e5;
}
.material-toggle input:checked ~ label:after {
  left: 15px;
  background-color: #1565c0;
  border-color: #1565c0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle" class=""></label>
  </div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle2" class=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need unique ids, currently they both have `id="toggle"`

```
<div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle" class=""></label>
  </div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle2" class=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: won't fix the problem itself

Comment: mmm yes it will

Comment: That's because your labels are both referencing id toggle, you need unique labels as well of course...

Comment: and you don't mentioned that in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle"  class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle" class=""></label>
  </div>
  <div class="material-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-2" name="toggle" class="switch" />
    <label for="toggle-2" class=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I resolved assigning different labels' **for** values. I did a material-theme switcher, but i used Javascript and Jquery to make it working with multiple switchers in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use different "id".
If I understand the question, the answer is:

```
<div>
    <div class="material-toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" name="toggle" checked=true class="switch" />
        <label for="toggle1" class=""></label>
    </div>
    <div class="material-toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" name="toggle" checked=false class="switch" />
        <label for="toggle2" class=""></label>
    </div>
</div>
```